# Use LINQ instead of two for loops

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert these two "ugly" *for* loops to a LINQ expression. Can anyone help me out? I am pretty new to LINQ. thanks in advance!

```
foreach (Edge edge in distinctEdge)
{
    var c = 0;
    foreach(Edge e in EdgeList)
    {
        if(e.target == edge.target && e.source == edge.source)
        {
            c++;
        }
    }
    edge.value = c;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/):

```
foreach (var edge in distinctEdge)
{
    edge.value = EdgeList.Count(e => e.target == edge.target && e.source == edge.source);
}
```

Comment: yeah, your answer is correct and I have to install this POWERFUL and WONDERFUL tool. Thanks Backs!

Comment: @doglas ReSharper is `must have` tool for c# development

Comment: CodeRush is also very nice tool.

Comment: ReSharper is a great tool, but some times readability and maintainability is first priority and ReSharper refactoring results can sometimes be harder to read and understand.

Comment: @togocoder of couse, first of all, code must be maintainable, but here is not problem with it, for me, it became better

Answer (score 4):

Something easy to read and understand

```
  var value=(from edge in distinctEdge
    join e in EdgeList
   on edge.Target equals e.Target
   and e.source equals edge.source
   select edge ).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Also works well. I believe this way is kind of like SQL join and find the mutual elements in two lists and then get the count of it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness answering the original question, I will propose the following BUT I don't believe it's as readable as using a foreach loop proposed by @dog-las for the update.  However, I did use this method of updating all objects in a collection using LINQ recently for a simpler update, so think it's handy.

```
var result = distinctEdge.Select(c =>
        {
            c.value = EdgeList.Count(e => e.target == c.target
                                          && e.source == c.source);
            return c;
        }).ToList();
```